# How can a structure that is declared as static const end up in RAM? (in C)

Tags: c

I am trying to port some hideously obfuscated code from Codewarrior to Crossworks. The libraries are written in C, but - I think - are trying to mimic C++ objects.

When these objects are declared they are done so with macros that use macros that use macros which makes it very difficult to follow! I have expanded them out using the preprocessor to make it a  little easier to understand.

Now, under the [working] Codwarrior Eclipse based system, there is a section of text, specified in the source code as static const that ends up in RAM. As far as I can see, other stuff that is specified as static const, the linker puts into flash. In Crossworks, it all ends up in flash - which to me makes sense.

Here's one example of a problematic declaration after it's been expanded from the macros:

```
static const D4D_LABEL scrSplash_lblSID_params
 = { {  "   Unit ID: 42949672955" , sizeof("   Unit ID: 42949672955"), 0, &scrSplash_lblSID_strPrties}, { 6, 76 }, { 118, 16 }, 8 };
```

D4D Label is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    D4D_STRING textBuff;    // label text
    D4D_POINT scrPos;        // position on the screen 
    D4D_SIZE  scrSize;       // size on the screen (focus rect only, bitmaps have own size)    
    D4D_COOR radius;         // corner radius 
} D4D_LABEL;
```

And D4D_STRING is defined below:

```
typedef struct D4D_STRING_S 
{
  char *pText;
  D4D_INDEX buffSize;
  D4D_FONT fontId;
  D4D_STR_PROPERTIES *str_properties;
  D4D_INDEX printLen;
  D4D_INDEX printOff;
}D4D_STRING;
```

This D4D_LABEL is put into a D4D_OBJECT as follows:

```
const D4D_OBJECT scrSplash_lblSID = { (void*)&(scrSplash_lblSID_params), (D4D_OBJECT_SYS_FUNCTION*)&d4d_labelSysFunc, 
(void*)0, (void*)0, (0x01 | 0x02 | 0x40), &(scrSplash_lblSID_flags), (void*)0, &(scrSplash_lblSID_pScreen) };
```

And D4D_OBJECT is defined thus:

```
// this is allocated in ROM always
typedef struct D4D_OBJECT_S
{
    void* pParam;
    D4D_OBJECT_SYS_FUNCTION* pObjFunc; 
    Byte (*OnUsrMessage)(struct D4D_MESSAGE_S* pMsg);    
    void *userPointer;
    D4D_OBJECT_INITFLAGS initFlags;
    D4D_OBJECT_FLAGS*  flags;
    struct D4D_CLR_SCHEME_S* clrScheme;
    struct D4D_SCREEN_S** pScreen;
} D4D_OBJECT;
```

So as far as I can see, the first thing put into the D4D_OBJECT scrSplash_lblSID is a pointer to the D4D_LABEL scrSplash_lblSID_params. That D4D label is declared as static const and so put into flash. Crossworks does that, Codewarrior has it in RAM though.

When this function is used:

```
void D4D_SetText(D4D_OBJECT_PTR pObject, char* pText) 
{
  D4D_STRING* p_TextBuff = NULL;

  if(pObject->pObjFunc->GetTextBuffer)
    p_TextBuff = pObject->pObjFunc->GetTextBuffer((D4D_OBJECT*)pObject);  

// ABOVE line equates to: return &(((D4D_LABEL*)((pThis)->pParam))->textBuff);  

  if(p_TextBuff)
  {
    D4D_ChangeText(p_TextBuff, pText, 0);  
    D4D_InvalidateObject(pObject, D4D_FALSE);
  }

}
```

By the following line:

```
D4D_SetText(&scrSplash_lblSID, SIdString);
```

p_TextBuff is a RAM location in Codewarrior and a flash location Crossworks. ChangeText function tries to copy the string pointed to by pText into flash and, of course, the processor (a Cortex M4 by Freescale - a Kinetis processor) crashes!

Is the above anywhere near enough information to be able to advise me? I am guessing there's something in the linker file on the Codewarrior project that somehow manages to make the relevant string end up in RAM not flash. I cannot see how the linker magically knows to put that static const in RAM and not flash like the other stuff!

The linker file is below just in case it might be relevant.

Many thanks!

```
# Default linker command file.
MEMORY {
  m_interrupts  (RX) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x000001E0             # Interrupts
  m_text        (RX) : ORIGIN = 0x00004400, LENGTH = 0x0003BC00             # Code and read only data
  m_data        (RW) : ORIGIN = 0x1FFF0000, LENGTH = 0x00020000             # Read/write data


}

KEEP_SECTION { .vectortable }
KEEP_SECTION { .cfmconfig }

SECTIONS {

.interrupts :
{
    __vector_table = .;
    * (.vectortable)
    . = ALIGN (0x4);
} > m_interrupts

# All the stuff that lives in flash: the application (.text), read only data (.rodata) and .init - whatever the latter is

.app_text:  
{
    ALIGNALL(4);
    * (.init)   
    * (.text)
        .= ALIGN(0x8) ;
    * (.rodata)
        .= ALIGN(0x4) ;
    ___ROM_AT = .;
} > m_text

# App data is INITIALISED data. So stuff that was specified in flash, but gets copied to RAM at boot

.app_data: AT(___ROM_AT)
{
    * (.sdata)
    * (.data)
        .= ALIGN(0x4) ;
    *(.ARM.extab)
        .= ALIGN(0x4) ;
       __exception_table_start__ = .;
    EXCEPTION
       __exception_table_end__ = .;
        .= ALIGN(0x4) ;
       __sinit__ = .;
    STATICINIT
    .= ALIGN(0x8) ;
} > m_data

# .bss is UNINITIALISED data that just lives in normal RAM - after the initialised stuff

.bss :
{
    .= ALIGN(0x4) ;
    __START_BSS = .;
    * (.bss)
    __END_BSS = .;
    .= ALIGN(0x8) ;
} >> m_data

_romp_at = ___ROM_AT + SIZEOF(.app_data);
.romp : AT(_romp_at)
{
    __S_romp = _romp_at;
    WRITEW(___ROM_AT);
    WRITEW(ADDR(.app_data));
    WRITEW(SIZEOF(.app_data));
    WRITEW(0);
    WRITEW(0);
    WRITEW(0);
}

__SP_INIT = . + 0x00008000;
__heap_addr = __SP_INIT;
__heap_size = 0x00008000;

}
```

Comment: The code you're porting is erroneously modifying that which is not supposed to be modified — this is undefined behaviour.  When you invoke undefined behaviour, anything can happen, including 'it works as expected' (CodeWarrior) and 'it crashes' (CrossWorks).  Both are behaving within specification.  You will need to fix the bug in the code, and expect to run into more instances of this since the old platform didn't spot it but the new does.  Are you compiling with enough warning flags on both platforms?  Are you sure there isn't one which will tell you when you try to modify a constant?

Comment: It's not a bug. This has been run on multiple products by multiple companies using Codewarrior. It's porting-to-Crossworks issue.

Comment: Yes, it is a bug. Writing to a string literal is undefined behavior, no matter how many other implementations let you get away with it. Just because you didn't get caught crossing a red light yesterday doesn't mean you won't today.

Comment: @user2401515 Whether it's been run multiple times by multiple companies is irrelevant. It's a bug in that it *relies* on undefined behavior and expects consistent behavior. If you want consistent behavior across compilers it helps to start by not invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Look for a linker script file or something that sets up sections on your platform.  This is the magical file that tells the linker where sections go in RAM - .text goes to 0xf00, .bss to 0xbabe, etc.  If this is setup to place strings into RAM on your system, you may be able to work around this issue.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: this is what I was thinking. I posted the original linker file at the bottom of my original post, but with my [rather limited] knowledge of linker files I could see nothing that would say strings go here. To my mind that is the most likely thing - something somewhere in the Codewarrior set-up is giving it the intelligence to stick strings in RAM. There's no way it just happens to get that right by accident on multiple processors over multiple instances of use of the libraries!

Comment: * (.rodata) is where your string will usually go (though .text might have it as well, look at your .map file to be sure).  Try moving that token to your app_data section.  That way, according to the comments, it will get copied into RAM and should be writable.

Comment: And, as others have said, this is probably a bug of some sort.  Unless your strings are declared mutable, they should not be writable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's irrelevant that the object is declared `static const`; the string that you're trying to write to is the pointer inside `D4D_STRING`:

```
typedef struct D4D_STRING_S 
{
  char *pText;
```

This is initialized from the string literal `"   Unit ID: 42949672955"`, and it is undefined behavior to write to a string literal.

If your compiler accepts the `-fwritable-strings` option (gcc before 4.0, some versions of clang) then you can use that option to put string literals in RAM.  The preferred alternative is to use a mutable character buffer:

```
char scrSplash_lblSID_params_text[] = "   Unit ID: 42949672955";
```

Comment: Using `-fwritable-strings` is an obsolete band aid to work around the bug of modifying constant data.  It is best to fix the bug.

Comment: There quite simply *is* no bug per se. The program is crashing because in Crossworks the string "   Unit ID: 42949672955" is in flash and in Codewarrior it is in RAM. It runs exactly as expected in Codewarrior and it comes from functions written by the folks at Freescale.

It must surely be a linker thing and surely Codewarrior is doing something clever that says something like "Any string defined must automatically be put on flash"?

Comment: Or could it be even more clever and somehow Codewarrior says: "Oh, look that  string is being written to/modified, therefore we must have it stored in RAM"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "Any string defined must automatically be put in RAM"?

Comment: @user No, there quite clearly *is* a bug. You're spending more time looking for a switch to get your new compiler to work with broken code than just fixing the code.

Comment: This line did it:

char scrSplash_lblSID_params_text[] = "   Unit ID: 42949672955";



Then using that in the macros:



D4D_DECLARE_RLABEL(scrSplash_lblSID, scrSplash_lblSID_params_text, SPLASH_RDM_LABEL_POSX, SPLASH_RDM_LABEL_POSY, SPLASH_RDM_LABEL_SIZEX, SPLASH_RDM_LABEL_SIZEY, SPLASH_RDM_LABEL_RADIUS, 
                  (D4D_OBJECT_F_VISIBLE | D4D_OBJECT_F_ENABLED | D4D_OBJECT_F_FOCUSRECT), NULL, FONT_ARIAL7, NULL, NULL)

Comment: While this makes an important point, I'm sorry to see this accepted as the answer when it does not actually answer the question as to RAM vs FLASH, and there is an answer which does.

Comment: My friend who writes compilers said the original code is "Bad beyond belief" which made me laugh! ecatmur, you were spot-on in every way; it's undefined and will work with some compilers and not with others - just depends on the compiler. So, for Codewarrior, it's not a bug, even though it might be terribly bad practice.

Comment: Even once you fully comply with the C standard, the practical ability to write to strings which C considers mutable *still* depends on having the sections of your linker map properly configured - it's just more likely that the out-of-the-box default map (if provided) will get that right.

Answer (score 3):

Added as an answer as well:

Look for a linker script file or something that sets up sections on your platform. This is the magical file that tells the linker where sections go in RAM - .text goes to 0xf00, .bss to 0xbabe, etc. If this is setup to place strings into RAM on your system, you may be able to work around this issue.

Comment: This answer speaks to the actual mechanism behind where the item ends up - the others address only a different, albeit also important, issue.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR

The short answer to the question in the title is: because it's not specified by the C Language Standard. A C implementation is free to store static const objects where it wants.

And string literals can be placed in read-only memory, so don't try to modify them.

Comment: While very true, it's more of a comment since they are talking about a specific platform.

Comment: So how does Codewarrior's linker (or indeed, any other linker) know which static const to put in RAM and which in flash?!

Comment: The linker script or equivalent mechanism, see Michael Dorgan's answer.